# taking database back up of SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, asp.net, database-backup

I have  a requirement where I need to take the backup of database. Once the user clicks the  button I need back up the entire database to the location

```
 c:/backup
```

Database: SQL Server 2005.

Thank  you

Answer (score 2):

You're asking for quite a bit of information in one question, but to start, you can refer to the [T-SQL syntax for backing up a database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191304.aspx):

```
BACKUP DATABASE MyDatabase
TO DISK = 'c:\backup.bak'
```

Answer (score 0):

Look [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191304.aspx). You'll need to execute code analogous to this via `SqlCommand`:

- Create and open `SqlConnection` with user/pwd allowing maintenance operations on DB.
- Create `SqlCommand` for this connection with proper command text (see linked article).
- Call `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery`.

Or else you may use Sql Server object model (SMO) to make a backup. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162133.aspx) (assemblies you need to reference are listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162129.aspx)).

Comment: THIS  GIVES  ME  TAKING BACK  UP   FROM SQLSERVER   . I NEED   TO ACHIVE THIS  FUNCTIONALITY  IN  FRONT END  USING ASP.NET.